# php code unexpectedly printed in window

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to test some mysql query's to check how to compare some dates to today's date, however instead of executing the code, a part is printed on the screen. this is the code.

```
<?

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","Username","Password","makeamemo");
$result = mysqli_query($db, 'DELETE FROM `messages` WHERE CURRENT_DATE() >= `Date`');
if(!$result){
    die('No messages deleted...');
}else{
    die('Messages deleted...');
}

?>
```

Everything behind the greater than sign in the mysqli_query is printed instead of executed. I have tried to fix it with a `\` to make sure the mysql sees the > as a character. I also checked if it worked to switch the `=` and `>`. I guess php thinks the code ends there, but I don't know how to solve this.
I wanted the code to delete all row's that contain a date that has already passed and die saying if it worked.

Comment: You probably just don't have short tags enabled. Change `<?` to `<?php`

Comment: How stupid... I just forgot that. Sorry. Never looked at that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**NEVER** use php short tags `<?` because these can be turned off in `php.ini` and then  source of your script is sent as plain text. Always use `<?php` and you;d be on safe ground

Comment: Why do short tags exist?Some legacy?

Comment: Yep (it also affects all the `<?=` shortcuts - avoid these as well). But the worst thing here is not that such thing exists, but that it can be disable and the consequences of that are very bad.